# Add function for cancel in UIAlert of Phone Call function

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have a function that places a phone call when a button is pressed.

```
private func callNumber(phoneNumber:String) {

  if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)") {

    let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
      if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
          application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add some functionality if the users hit cancel when the alert pops up to confirm the call. How would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I create a UIAlertView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022479/how-would-i-create-a-uialertview-in-swift)

Comment: @bearacuda13 this question is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this question: [Prompt when trying to dial a phone number using tel:// scheme on iOS 10.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121740/prompt-when-trying-to-dial-a-phone-number-using-tel-scheme-on-ios-10-3)

This alert is actually a bug in iOS 10.3 and should be removed at some point in the future. It isn't supposed to come up for "tel:" links in native apps.

That said, I don't believe there is a way to detect the alert and how the user interacts with it.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you! I thought it was weird I had no control over the UIAlert but wasn't sure if maybe there was something in the documentation I missed.