# Making phone calls in iOS apps

Tags: ios, openurl

It used to be, before iOS 10.3; that we had the choice inside an iOS app on how to perform a phone call.
Either using this, in which case the call was executed immediately:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://01-2345-6789"]];
```

Or using this, in which case the call was executed only after waiting for a user confirmation:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://01-2345-6789"]];
```

Now even the first option waits for user confirmation. Is there a way to avoid waiting? It would be great to at least give the choice to the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prompt when trying to dial a phone number using tel:// scheme on iOS 10.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121740/prompt-when-trying-to-dial-a-phone-number-using-tel-scheme-on-ios-10-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Both the `tel` and `telprompt` schemes prompt the user before attempting to make a call.

Comment: OK thanks. So now there is no difference between the two schemes? Anyway as a result it currently takes two steps for the user to make a phone call instead of one before.

Comment: Yep. It stinks. (I have an app that it affects as well)