# Xamarin.forms ios open dialer without alert box

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Essentials Phone Dialer in my xamarin forms app to make calls. In android when we click call it will directly open dialer. In ios when we click call it will firstly show a alert box that will ask  **Call** or **cancel**. Is it possible to open the dialer in ios without showing the popup? If it is not possible can we get the alert box **cancel** or **call** click event?

[image]

Comment: That is native ios behaviour and i do not think that can be changed. But lemme see if I can find something

Comment: @FreakyAli That will be a great help bro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prompt when trying to dial a phone number using tel:// scheme on iOS 10.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121740/prompt-when-trying-to-dial-a-phone-number-using-tel-scheme-on-ios-10-3)

Comment: @FreakyAli I saw that question, so thats why I asked to get the cancel or call button click event

Comment: You cannot get that either what exactly are you trying to achieve anyway?

Comment: @Iam trying to show a popup if user placed the call. The popup intitialised after the call button click.But I want it to be show only when call placed. Not when the user clicked the cancel button

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in iOS.

From Apple's documentation:

> **openURL**
>
> When a third party application invokes openURL: on a tel://,
>   facetime://, or facetime-audio:// URL, iOS displays a prompt and
>   requires user confirmation before dialing.

For security reasons, iOS requires users to confirm they want to perform the call before dialing in.

Comment: Ok . Is it possible to get the cancel and call button event?

Comment: No, this is a system dialog and there's not any callback or event to subscribe to. A simple way to figure out if the user went to dialer (hit on Call) would be by subscribing to the app event when the app is going to background. This is just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to open the dialer in ios without showing the popup?

No, it is by design.

> can we get the alert box cancel or call click event

You have to detect the state of phone call by yourself in the iOS project, you can write below codes in the `AppDelegate`:

```
    CXCallObserver callObserver = new CXCallObserver();
    callObserver.SetDelegate(new myDelegate(), DispatchQueue.MainQueue);
```

And in the delegate, you can check the call state:

```
  public class myDelegate : ICXCallObserverDelegate
    {
        public IntPtr Handle => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void CallChanged(CXCallObserver callObserver, CXCall call)
        {
            if (call.Outgoing==true && call.HasConnected ==false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dialing");
                //use Messaging Center to send the state to Xamarin.forms Project.
            }

            if (call.Outgoing ==false && call.HasConnected == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("disconnect");
                //use Messaging Center to send the state to Xamarin.forms Project.
            }
            //you can use other state to check the state...
            //call.OnHold; call.HasEnded;

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Detect the state change to know if user click the cancel or button.

Comment: Let me check bro.